# How do you configure WYSIHTML5 toolbar feedback?

Tags: jquery, wysihtml5

On the demo of WYSIHTML5 the toolbar feeds back to show you the selected options you have selected. i.e. if you click on an item that is bold the toolbar reflects this.

How do you configure this?